# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text' - Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have an issue when extracting the text in a span in beautifulsoup:

```
data = requests.get("https://www.habitaclia.com/pisos-barcelona.htm?gclid=Cj0KCQiAkuP9BRCkARIsAKGLE8UM9G9s2MhPVtfXl2wo81qT62dqCwkVeV1zVSlPz_G1Nt0QcSoyKTYaAv55EALw_wcB")

soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text, "html5lib")

anuncis = soup.find_all("div", {"class":"list-item-info"})

data = []
for anunci in anuncis:
    preu = [anunci.find("span", attrs={"itemprop": "price"}).text]
    data.append(preu) 
print(data)
```

I tried different parsers html, html5, xlml but none seems to work.

Any idea why I can't extract the text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like some of `div.list-item-info` have no `span` with `itemprop=price` inside. So, you need check them like this

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data=requests.get("https://www.habitaclia.com/pisos-barcelona.htm?gclid=Cj0KCQiAkuP9BRCkARIsAKGLE8UM9G9s2MhPVtfXl2wo81qT62dqCwkVeV1zVSlPz_G1Nt0QcSoyKTYaAv55EALw_wcB")

soup=BeautifulSoup(data.text, "lxml")

anuncis = soup.find_all("div", {"class":"list-item-info"})

data=[]
for anunci in anuncis:
    preu = anunci.find("span", attrs={"itemprop":"price"})
    if preu:
        data.append([preu.text])
print(data)
```

Result

```
[['190.000 €'], ['156.371 €'], ['256.489 €'], ['218.000 €'], ['225.000 €'], ['480.000 €'], ['1.325.000 €'], ['439.000 €'], ['1.495.000 €'], ['339.000 €'], ['780.000 €'], ['549.000 €'], ['549.000 €'], ['535.000 €'], ['460.000 €']]
```