# How can I solve this NoneType Web Scraping Attribute Error in the following code?

Tags: python, attributeerror

While doing the web scraping of the webpage, the error of (AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text') occurred. How can I eliminate this error?

My code is:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests

url = "https://www.pararius.com/apartments/amsterdam?ac=1"

page = requests.get(url=url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

lists = soup.find_all('section', class_="listing-search-item")

for list in lists:

    title = list.find('a', class_="listing-search-item_link--title").text

    location = list.find('div', class_="listing-search-item__location").text

    price = list.find('div', class_="listing-search-item__price").text

    area = list.find('li', class_="illustrated-features__item illustrated-features__item-- 
    surface-area").text

    info = [title, location, price, area]

    print(info)
```

Comment: which line throw the error?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You cant use BeautifulSoup to scrape a website that uses javascript to load the data. Try using Selenium.

Comment: Don't use `list` as a variable name

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/64949431/6045800

Answer (score 1):

This error is because sometimes there is no element found then its returns `None` and you try `None.text`. Then This error is thrown.

Here you can use `try-except` block.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests

url = "https://www.pararius.com/apartments/amsterdam?ac=1"

page = requests.get(url=url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

lists = soup.find_all('section', class_="listing-search-item")

for list_ in lists:
    try:
        title = list_.find('a', class_="listing-search-item_link--title").text
    except AttributeError:
        title=None

    try:
        location = list_.find('div', class_="listing-search-item__location").text

    except AttributeError:
        location = None
    try:
        price = list_.find('div', class_="listing-search-item__price").text
    except AttributeError:
        price = None

    try:
        area = list_.find('li', class_="illustrated-features__item illustrated-features__item-- surface-area").text
    except AttributeError:
        area = None

    info = [title, location, price, area]

    print(info)
```

I know the above one is messy But There is another method.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests

url = "https://www.pararius.com/apartments/amsterdam?ac=1"

page = requests.get(url=url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

lists = soup.find_all('section', class_="listing-search-item")

def function(element):
    if element is not None:
        return element.text
    return None
for list_ in lists:

    title = function(list_.find('a', class_="listing-search-item_link--title"))

    location = function(list_.find('div', class_="listing-search-item__location"))

    price = function(list_.find('div', class_="listing-search-item__price"))

    area = function(list_.find('li', class_="illustrated-features__item illustrated-features__item-- surface-area"))
    

    info = [title, location, price, area]

    print(info)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `try` `except` block

```
  try:  
    title = list.find('a', class_="listing-search-item_link--title").text
  except AttributeError:
    title = None
```

See [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html)

Answer (score 0):

Add function definition immediately after `import requests` as follows

```
def get_text(elem):
    return None if elem is None else elem.text
```

then use it like so replace

```
title = list.find('a', class_="listing-search-item_link--title").text
```

using

```
title = get_text(list.find('a', class_="listing-search-item_link--title"))
```

Explanation: this function use ternary operators and when elem is None it does return None, otherwise elem.text. As side note using name of built-in (`list`) is bad idea in `python` as it does overshadow said built-in.

Comment: Issue the op has is that the website uses javascript to fetch the data that he wants to scrape...